# Reproduce a Timing Attack with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, curl, timing-attack

I'm trying to recreate a Timing Attack with Node.js for training purpose.

I think I'm doing something wrong, because I was expecting other results.

I've created a simple and basic Node app:

```js
const express = require('express');
  
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const password = 'cbfa'
    const input = req.query.input
    console.log(password, input)
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.set('Connection', 'close')
        if(password === input) {
            res.send('ok')
        } else {
            res.send('no')
        }
    }, 3000)
})
  
app.listen(PORT, (error) =>{
    if(!error)
        console.log('App is listening on port ' + PORT)
    else 
        console.log('Error occurred', error)
    }
)
```

When hitting `http://localhost:3001/`, it looks for an `input` parameter and compare it with the `password`, in this case 'cbfa'.

I've also created a `curl-format.txt` that shows the URL being called and the time total:

```
url: %{url}\n
time_total:  %{time_total}\n
--------------------------------------------\n
```

and a `urls.txt` that contains the URL to be called:

```
url = "http://localhost:3000?input=aaaa"
url = "http://localhost:3000?input=bbbb"
url = "http://localhost:3000?input=cccc"
url = "http://localhost:3000?input=dddd"
```

With the app running, I run this:

`curl --parallel --parallel-max 4 --config urls.txt -v -o /dev/null -s -w "@curl-format.txt"`

Being the password 'cbfa', I was expecting the URL with `?input=cccc` to take more time than the other, but this is the result:

```
url: http://localhost:3000?input=aaaa
time_total:  3.036737
--------------------------------------------
url: http://localhost:3000?input=bbbb
time_total:  3.055791
--------------------------------------------
url: http://localhost:3000?input=cccc
time_total:  3.056294
--------------------------------------------
url: http://localhost:3000?input=dddd
time_total:  3.070444
--------------------------------------------
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: There are probably many other factors which will affect the timing such as OS process prioritization, network traffic, etc. I would try with a much larger string until you can get repeatable results.

Comment: The endpoint doesn't provide a difference in timing to detect. Both the positive and negative responses are behind the same 3 second delay.  What would cause `cccc` to take more time?